# how to send an simple data from an activity to fragment ? Here i want to pass data from Dashboard Activity to the FrstFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

This is My Dashboard class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    //is this the fragment tht vl be called first ??

    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    //setting the username and password

    username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password"); 

    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    //unable to pass these data present in username and password to the next fragment 

    b.putString("username",username);
    b.putString("password",password);
    f.setArguments(b);   
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    //is this the correct way to cal fragments on click of a menu item

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.nav_inbox){
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction 
        fragmentTransaction =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
        fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard)
    {
        //should i each time right FragmentTransaction

        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction 
        fragmentTransaction =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
        fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
}
```

This is my Fragment:

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    musername = getArguments().getString("username");
    mpassword = getArguments().getString("password");

    //is this correct format to cal a bundle in Fragment

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    if (b!=null) {

        //unable to get the data

        musername = b.getString("username");
        mpassword = b.getString("password");
    }
        if(musername != null && mpassword != null){
        mname.setText("" +mpassword);
        mid.setText("" +musername);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you commit fragment then insert arguments?

Comment: i m new to android...cn u explain it t me

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit(); before calling those lines insert your argurments to fragment,

Comment: //is this correct ??

FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("username",username);
        b.putString("password",password);
        f.setArguments(b);

        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: yep should work now.

Comment: nope not working

Comment: Is my coding style is wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Create this method in Fragment named Table Fragment and ITEM_CLICKED is key in which data is stored. Make key a public static final string.

```
   public static Fragment getInstance(int item) {
       TableFragment tableFragment = new TableFragment();
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putInt(ITEM_CLICKED, item);
       tableFragment.setArguments(bundle);
       return tableFragment;
    }
```

Call this in onCreateView() in Fragment class..........

```
    int item = getArguments().getInt(ITEM_CLICKED);
```

Invoke Fragment From Activity using...........

```
 TableFragment.getInstance(2);
```